# How to select multiple input fields and remove the required attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem selecting multiple input fields and remove the required attribute.
I use Php/ Symfony3 and created multiple forms in one page. Both of the forms work and they send the right information back to the Client.

The forms are called shippingAddress and billingAddress, but when a user says both of the forms are the same it is useless to fill in both. So i decided to create a piece of code to set all data to null (from the billingAddress) and send it back to the Client. Works perfect!

Now the problem, because i want to have a few required fields they need to fill in when the addresses are not the same. It wont send the form, because it says some of the input fields are not filed in yet.

I created some examples, but it does not look nice to me. Is there a better way to do it with the same outcome?
**not all fields are required**

*Edit:
Forgot the important thing of my question, the required option needs to be toggled.*

## 1

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#form_check").click(function(){
                $("#form_billingAddress").fadeToggle();
                $("#form_billingAddress_firstName").removeAttr('required');
                $("#form_billingAddress_lastName").removeAttr('required');
                $("#form_billingAddress_email").removeAttr('required');
                $("#form_billingAddress_streetName").removeAttr('required');
                $("#form_billingAddress_streetNumber").removeAttr('required');
                $("#form_billingAddress_city").removeAttr('required');
                $("#form_billingAddress_pOBox").removeAttr('required');
                $("#form_billingAddress_phone").removeAttr('required');
            });
        });
#2
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $("#form_check").on("click",function(){
                $("#form_billingAddress").fadeToggle();
                $("#form_billingAddress_firstName, " +
                    "#form_billingAddress_lastName, " +
                    "#form_billingAddress_email, " +
                    "#form_billingAddress_streetName, " +
                    "#form_billingAddress_streetNumber, " +
                    "#form_billingAddress_city, " +
                    "#form_billingAddress_pOBox, " +
                    "#form_billingAddress_phone").removeAttr('required');
            });
        });
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS3 selectors in jQuery.
Documentation for the selectors on [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("#form_check").on("click",function(){
        $("#form_billingAddress").fadeToggle();
        $("input[id^='form_billingAddress_']").removeAttr('required'); // the tick
    });
});
```

With toggle:

```
var required = true;
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("#form_check").on("click",function(){
        $("#form_billingAddress").fadeToggle();
        if(required){
            $("input[id^='form_billingAddress_']").removeAttr('required');
        }else{
            $("input[id^='form_billingAddress_']").attr('required', true);
        }
        required = !required;
    });
});
```

It's faster to use an variable than check if the elements are required. That's why I choose for this.

**Edit:** It can better, doing this:

```
var required = true;
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("#form_check").on("click",function(){
        $("#form_billingAddress").fadeToggle();
        $("input[id^='form_billingAddress_']").attr('required',required);
        required = !required;
    });
});
```

Comment: I accept this as my answer, i changed the var required = true; to false and it works perfect! Thank you

Comment: After a while i discovered something, when i select the checkbox and deselect it again. Everything will be required, i am still using the concept of this solution but in a different way. A required form in my form builder looks now like this `$builder->add('firstName', TextType::class, ['attr' => ['data-required' => 'true']]); 
` and in the javascript i changed it to `$("#form_billingAddress input[data-required='true']").attr('required',required);` the rest stays the same.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** As the answer given already covers the usage of **partial selector** like

`$("input[id^='form_billingAddress_']").removeAttr('required');`

**2)** You can also **make use of class** . Add a class to all the input elements which you want to select and remove the attribute at once. lets use the class name as `form_billingAddress` .

`$(".form_billingAddress']").removeAttr('required');`

---

When it comes to performance the **Second option is faster**

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array to iterate over.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#form_check").click(function(){
            $("#form_billingAddress").fadeToggle();
            var $arr = [];
            $arr.push($("#form_billingAddress_firstName"),
            $("#form_billingAddress_lastName"),
            $("#form_billingAddress_email"),
            $("#form_billingAddress_streetName"),
            $("#form_billingAddress_streetNumber"),
            $("#form_billingAddress_city"),
            $("#form_billingAddress_pOBox"),
            $("#form_billingAddress_phone"))

            $arr.forEach(function(v,i){
                $(v)..removeAttr('required');
            })
        });
    });
```

**EDIT:**  There are more elegant ways to do what you want.